# Mail not sending to CC in PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using

```
    require("smtp-mail/smtp.php");
    $from                       =   "abc@abcd.com";   
    $cc                     =   'test@test.com';
    $to                     =   'xyz@xyz.com';
    $smtp                       =   new smtp_class;
    $smtp->host_name            =   "localhost";
    $smtp->host_port            =   25;
    $smtp->ssl                  =   0;              
    $smtp->start_tls            =   0;              
    $smtp->localhost            =   "localhost";    
    $smtp->direct_delivery      =   0;              
    $smtp->timeout              =   10;             
    $smtp->data_timeout     =   0;             
    $smtp->debug                =   0;             
    $smtp->html_debug           =   0;             
    $smtp->pop3_auth_host       =   "";             
    $smtp->user             =   "";             
    $smtp->realm                =   "";             
    $smtp->password         =   "";             
    $smtp->workstation          =   "";             
    $smtp->authentication_mechanism="";

if($smtp->direct_delivery)
{
if(!function_exists("GetMXRR"))
{
    $_NAMESERVERS       =   array();
    include("smtp-mail/getmxrr.php");
}
}
$smtp->SendMessage
(
$from,
array($to),
array
(
"MIME-Version: 1.0",
"From: 'IndianMoney.com'<test@test.com>",
"Cc: $cc",
"Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1",
"To: $to",
"Subject:". $mailSubject,
"Date: ".strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
),
$mailBody
);
```

Mail sent to $to
but not sending to $cc

Comment: Check the mail server logs? Are you sure the mail server was set up correctly? There's no "mail forwarder discovery protocol", so you have to manually configure your mail server to know how to find your ISP's mail server unless you want to run your own delivery server, which is a pretty big job.

Comment: other mails except cc mail are working properly

Comment: 100% confirm that if you swap to `to` and `cc` addresses, it's the `cc` recipient that doesn't get the mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List **all** envelope recipients ( "To", "Cc" and "Bcc") in the second parameter:

```
$smtp->SendMessage
(
$from,
array($to,$cc),
...
```

My guess it that SendMessage expects to get **all** recipients in the second parameter.